# Variable not defined - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, var

I am coding an AI. It's not working. The browser is saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: do is not defined.

```
var what = ["jokes", "cats", "news", "weather", "sport"];

function start() {

    var do = what[Math.floor((Math.random() * what.length) + 1)];
}
start();
Document.write(do);
```

Comment: read about function scope in javascript (basically variables defined within function are only visible inside that function)

Comment: Like mic4ael said, this is an issue with "scopes" in Javascript. 'do' is defined within a function, and thus not available outside. If you initialized 'do' outside of the function, you'll be able to access it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/480/scope#t=201608182147440316607

Comment: "do" is a JavaScript reserved word. I'd suggest to use other name.

Comment: you should declare variable outsite function and `what[Math.floor(Math.random() * what.length) + 1]` here `+1` always return empty. try `what[Math.floor(Math.random() * what.length)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do variable is out of scope

```
var what = ["jokes", "cats", "news", "weather", "sport"];

function start() {

    var do = what[Math.floor((Math.random() * what.length) + 1)];
}
start();
Document.write(do);
```

You need to change your code to

```
var what = ["jokes", "cats", "news", "weather", "sport"];

function start(callback) {

    var do = what[Math.floor((Math.random() * what.length) + 1)];
    callback(do);
}
start(function(val) {document.write(val)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var what = ["jokes", "cats", "news", "weather", "sport"];
var do;
function start() {

    do = what[Math.floor((Math.random() * what.length) + 1)];
}
start();
Document.write(do);
```

Answer (score 0):

do is a variable here and not a function.

```
var do = what[Math.floor((Math.random() * what.length) + 1)];
```

to create a do function, you would do something like this.

```
var what = ["jokes", "cats", "news", "weather", "sport"];
var do;
function start() {    
    do = function(){ return what[Math.floor((Math.random() * what.length) + 1)]};
}
start();
Document.write(do());
```

Comment: And how would this work? Pretty sure that's invalid JavaScript you got there: `do = function() = {`? And `document.write(do)` would write `function() {...}`, not the result of calling the function.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: some typos... and invalids.. changed...

Answer (score 0):

Do is only present inside your function. Read about function scope :) Try this:

```
var what = ["jokes", "cats", "news", "weather", "sport"];
var do = undefined;
function start() {
    do = what[Math.floor((Math.random() * what.length) + 1)];
}
start();
Document.write(do);
```